Pass a transaction to a function and do a query
I am attempting to use SQLx with SQLite to:

Begin a transaction.
Pass it to a function.
Execute two queries on it within the function.

I am struggling to determine what the function's transaction argument should be, and how to use the transaction within the function.
The only official example I saw concerned PostgreSQL and adapting it to SQLite did not work.
ChatGPT 4 also failed to give me a working example:
// sqlx = { version = "0.7.4", features = ["runtime-tokio-rustls", "sqlite"] }
// tokio = { version = "1.36.0", features = ["full"] }

use sqlx::sqlite::{SqlitePool, Sqlite};
use sqlx::{Pool, Transaction, Error};

async fn execute_query(tx: &mut Transaction<'_, Sqlite>) -> Result<(), Error> {
    sqlx::query("INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('Alice')")
        .execute(tx)
        .await?;
    Ok(())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let pool: Pool<Sqlite> = SqlitePool::connect("sqlite::memory:").await?;
    let mut tx = pool.begin().await?;
    execute_query(&mut tx).await?;
    tx.commit().await?;
    Ok(())
}

Producing this error:
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&mut Transaction<'_, Sqlite>: Executor<'_>` is not satisfied
   --> src\main.rs:9:18
    |
6   |         .execute(tx)
    |          ------- ^^ the trait `Executor<'_>` is not implemented for `&mut Transaction<'_, Sqlite>`
    |          |
    |          required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `Executor<'c>`:
              <&'c mut SqliteConnection as Executor<'c>>
              <&'c mut AnyConnection as Executor<'c>>
              <&Pool<DB> as Executor<'p>>


It looks like you need to get the underlying connection from the transaction and use that. Try .execute(&mut **tx).

It seems to work, is this the correct and intended usage, and will all queries made from the same transaction be rolled back or committed together, as expected?

Considering this is how it was done in the example you linked, why would you think otherwise? Nothing will be committed until you call .commit()... Transactions are usually stateful on the connection.

I must've mis-read the original article, I recall it giving me trouble in a way that suggested that SQLite needs to be handled differently. Thanks for the help.

a pointer to the underlying connection seems to have fixed the identical error for me:
 .execute(&mut **tx)

I get a different error without passing in the mutable reference as well.
